# Is there a way I can remove the need for a null check in a C# if that later checks for a != ""?

Tags: c#

I tried some different combinations but this was the only combination I could get to work as the comparison != "" seemed to give a problem for a null:

```
        if (options.English != null && options.English != "")
        {
            if (options.English.StartsWith("^"))
            {
                query = query.Where(w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Trim().Substring(1)));
            }
            else
            {
                query = query.Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English.Trim()));
            }
        }
```

Is there any way that I could optimize this to simplify it down to just one if statement or even two if statements that follow each other rather than have an outer and an inner if statement.

Comment: Are you using C# 6.0? You may want to look into null propagation, you could get rid of that entire check all together.

Comment: Have you tried string.IsNullOrEmpty()?

Comment: You have three cases: StartsWith, Contains, and neither. Three cases require two conditionals to distinguish.

Comment: @maxshuty I am VS2015 latest but not sure if that is C# 6 or not.  Do you know how I can check this and if it was 6.0 how could the code be changed?

Comment: @Anne see this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx and then  you should be able to Just do `options?.English`

Comment: @maxshuty: You're addressing a case that isn't a problem (when `options == null`) but the question is only concerned about `options.English` being null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **all** you're trying to do is remove the nested `if`s, then you can store the lambdas in a `Dictionary`

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<bool, Func<Options, bool>>() {
    { true, w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Trim().Substring(1)) },
    { false, w => w.English.Contains(options.English.Trim())} };

if (options.English != null && options.English != "")
{
    query = query.Where(lookup[options.English.StartsWith("^")]);
}
```

Now, by using [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) together with [`?:`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) you can indeed get this down to one statement...and it's not even horrid:

```
query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English) ?
    query : query.Where(lookup[options.English.StartsWith("^")]);
```

But, given that you've got only two options, a `Dictionary` isn't really needed, just use a few locals:

```
Func<Options, bool> startsWithCaret = w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Trim().Substring(1));
Func<Options, bool> doesNotStartWithCaret = w => w.English.Contains(options.English.Trim());
var lambda = options.English.StartsWith("^") ? startsWithCaret : doesNotStartWithCaret;
```

You're statement is now

```
query = String.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English) ? query : query.Where(lambda);
```

Not an `if` to be found! :-)

Comment: I'm not sure of the way lookup works.  I'm using Entity Framework and SQL Server.  Do you think this would work with EF ?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`.

To remove the nesting, you can do (C# 6)

```
if (options.English?.StartsWith("^") == true) {
    ...
} else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't remove the nested `if` statements as the question is asking for

Comment: Thanks, I did not know of that check and it would at least make it a bit clearer which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: @SLaks Your code is now no longer equivalent to the OP's code, and also is still nesting `if` statements.

Comment: @radarbob That has now changed the result.  There are 3 code paths in the OP's code, and only two in yours.

Comment: I am getting the error:  CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) On the first line when I tried the options.English?.StartsWith("^"))

Comment: @Anne: Sorry; you need `== true` or `?? false` to tell it to exclude `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It's trivial to transform an outer `if` with no else into a longer chain without nesting.

```
if (A) {
    if (B) { ... }
}
```

becomes

```
if (!A)
{ /* do nothing */ }
else if (B) { ... }
```

In your case, that's

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English))
    { /* do nothing */ }
else if (options.English.StartsWith("^"))
    {
        query = query.Where(w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Trim().Substring(1)));
    }
else
    {
        query = query.Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English.Trim()));
    }
```

Note that according to the language rules, the `if (B) ... else` actually is nested inside the first else, but human programmers don't present or think of it as nesting, rather as a chain.

Comment: So, as you've said, you *still* have nested `if` statements, now there's just a confusing empty block in there in addition to the nested `if` statements.

Comment: @Servy: It's what OP asked for (two if statements that follow each other).  He simply didn't realize that a chain is still nesting from the compiler perspective.  If he thinks about it differently, that's a good enough reason to turn it around.

Comment: But your `if` statement *doesn't* follow the other.  It's nested inside of it.

Comment: @Servy: Well, the first `if` could have a `return;` or `break;`, then the `else` wrapped around the rest wouldn't be necessary.  Depends on the surrounding structure of code that we aren't shown.  But this if chain is conceptually treated as a sequence, the nesting is an artifact of the compile process and not actually a useful way to think of it..

Comment: @BenVoigt - One of the comments was about C# 6.0 which I think I am using (latest version of VS2015).  Would using that simplify your answer?

Comment: If you want to argue that it's okay for the `if` statements to be nested, then that's an argument that there's no reason to ask the question (a reasonable thing to say in a comment) but it's still not an answer to the question to say that you think that they should just nest the `if` statements anyway, rather than avoiding it.

Comment: @Anne No, that comment was simply wrong in thinking that that feature was relevant to your situation, as it provided code that wasn't equivalent.

Comment: @Anne: No, you need to reach three different paths so this is as simple as it gets.  Michael Liu had already left a comment mentioning that so I didn't bother repeating it.

Comment: @Servy: Nesting inside an `else` is better for programmers, because thinking about a chain is easier than thinking about a tree.  Nevermind that the compiler builds a tree to store the chain, **the conceptual model of a chain still works**.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most performant, but likely the shortest way with only an if for null would be

```
if (!options.English.IsNullOrEmpty())
    query = query.Where(w =>
        w.English.Contains(string.Concat("^", options.English)
        .Replace("^^","^").Substring(1).Trim()));
```

Just put always a `^` in front of your string, replace (maybe) created `^^` with `^` and then you can always do a Substring(1).

Answer (score -1):

Your logic can be simplified to this:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English))
        {
            var s = options.English.Trim(); 
            query = query.Where(w => { return s.StartsWith("^") ? 
                w.English.StartsWith(s.Substring(1)) : w.English.Contains(s); });
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you refactor the code out into its own method then you can leverage a `return` statement to have separate `if` statements without nesting them:

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> AddOption(IEnumerable<Item> query, Option options)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.English))
        return query;
    if (options.English.StartsWith("^"))
        return query.Where(w => w.English.StartsWith(options.English.Trim().Substring(1)));
    return query = query.Where(w => w.English.Contains(options.English.Trim()));
}
```

You can then write `query = AddOptions(query, options)` to the method you've shown.